# SQL Query SUM and Divide by Distinct Date Count

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I assistance, I am looking for the sum of a data field and then want to divide it by the number of distinct dates in that field.

```
SUM(CASE WHEN dateResolved IS NOT NULL 
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 
    END) / DISTINCT(dateResolved) AvgPerDay
```

If there are 32 dates in dateResolved, with 5 distinct dates, I want it to return 6.4.

Comment: You need a count distinct, your distinct will just return the actual dates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default it does integer division you need :

```
SUM(CASE WHEN dateResolved IS NOT NULL 
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 
    END) * 1.0 / COUNT(DISTINCT dateResolved) AvgPerDay
```

However simply `count` would also work :

```
COUNT(dateResolved) * 1.0 / COUNT(DISTINCT dateResolved) AvgPerDay
```

`COUNT(dateResolved)` will ignore `null` values.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this as:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN dateResolved IS NOT NULL 
         THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 
    END) / COUNT(DISTINCT dateResolved) as AvgPerDay
```

But this is more simply phrased as:

```
COUNT(dateResolved) * 1.0 / COUNT(DISTINCT dateResolved) as AvgPerDay
```